# Limit collection size of an entity framework object

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an Entity Framework object A which contains a collection of objects B

In db context:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<A>(entity =>
        {   
            entity.HasOne(d => d.IdANavigation).WithMany(p => p.B)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdA);
        });
```

In the A entity object:

```
public partial class A
{
  public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; } = new List<B>();
}
```

When I query object A like so :

```
var a = await _context.A.FirstAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

I get the full list of B objects.

But I would like only the first 3 B objects in my A object.

How should I proceed?

Comment: The issue was a projectTo from automapper that removed the filter, the solution is to do the filter inside the AresponseModel object as so :
    public void Mapping(Profile profile)
    {
      profile.CreateMap<A, AResponseModel>().ForMember(m => m.B, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.B.Take(3)));
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Take()` looks to be supported by [filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) since at least EF Core 5:

> When applying Include to load related data, you can add certain enumerable operations to the included collection navigation, which allows for filtering and sorting of the results.
>
> Supported operations are: `Where`, `OrderBy`, `OrderByDescending`, `ThenBy`, `ThenByDescending`, `Skip`, and `Take`.

We should be able to get three child entities using:

```cs
var a = await _context.A
    .Include(a => a.Bs.Take(3))
    .FirstAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

Or a specific three child entities by expanding the filter:

```cs
var a = await _context.A
    .Include(a => a.Bs
        .Where(b => b.Foo == true)
        .OrderBy(b => b.Bar)
        .Skip(5)
        .Take(3))
    .FirstAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

---

Important to note that you can only specify a filter once per included relationship.

> Each included navigation allows only one unique set of filter operations. In cases where multiple Include operations are applied for a given collection navigation [...], filter operations can only be specified on one of them:

So the queries above are valid, but the following is not:

```cs
var a = await _context.A
    .Include(a => a.Bs.Where(b => b.Foo == true)
    
    // This is invalid! We already used a filter
    // in an include for a.Bs above...
    .Include(a => a.Bs.Take(3))

    .FirstAsync(m => m.Id == id);
```

---

Also important to note that you might see child entities that do not match your filter if those child entities are already present in the change tracker. This is because of [navigation fixup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/serialization):

> Because EF Core automatically does fix-up of navigation properties[...]

For example, if you are currently tracking all `B` objects:

```cs
var b = await _context.B.ToListAsync();
```

Then filtering `A.Bs` will still include all `B` children of the selected `A` even if they don't match the provided filter. The query run against the database will retrieve only the children matching the filter, but EF Core will check if any of the children being tracked belong to the requested parent and automatically add them to the collection being returned.

You can fix this by not reusing the `DbContext` for queries involving filtered includes, or using a [non-tracking query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking).

Comment: You are correct, it works! Took me some time to believe as I already tried that, it seems that is the next line that removes the filter which is automapper: var aResponseModel = await efA.ProjectTo<AResponseModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)